# Can a user destroy their php session

Tags: php

I was wondering if its possible for a user to destroy their session variables.

For example if they clear their cookies will that destroy their session variables? I want to make a system to log how many failed attempts were done by one person and was going to make a session variable instead of inserting the data into a SQL db. Any suggestions on the most efficient way would be great!

Comment: why not attaching a counter with the user? if the person is not the one he/she claiming to be, it's an abuse. as for ip, geo-ip localisation could help like, statistically speaking if user x always log from country X and at some point there is multiple failed attempt in a different country it's likely to be an abuse no?

Answer (score 3):

No, sessions are stored on the server in a `tmp` folder. All the user has is the session ID (which is usually stored in a cookie).

So even if the user clears their cookies, the session would stay active on the server, until PHPs garbage collection takes effect.

However, if the user does delete the session ID, the server would generate them a new one. There is no way to restrict how many login attempts a website visitor can make, but you can add restrictions to the amount of times a user account in the database can attempt to be logged in as.

You would do this, but altering the `users` table in the database. Add a `time_locked_out` field, and set it to default `null`, and a `login_attempts` field, with default `0`.

If the account is attempted to be logged in more than 3 times, set the `time_locked_out` field to the current time, and dont let it attempt to be logged in again until 30 minutes after that time (or whatever).

Comment: Ok so just to make sure they can dissassociate themselves from there session id right? Because I was going to keep a counter of the failed attempts by that user in a session variable but I want to make sure they cant do something such as clean there cookies and have that counter be reset since they have a new id.

Comment: If they deleted their cookies, the counter would technically be reset, because when they go back to your website, the server would generate a new session, and set the counter to `0`. You would need to restrict the amount of times a user can try to log in using your database, rather than relying on sessions or cookies.

Answer (score 3):

You don't really want to count failed login attempts *by one person*; rather, you want to count failed login attempts *against one account*. This needs a session-spanning mechanism, so you should go back to the drawing board.

For example, you can keep a "last failed login" and "count of recent failed logins" column in your users table. Also, decide on a failed login threshold (# of logins after which defensive measures are taken) and a wariness timespan (if that much time passes without failed logins the counter is reset).

Whenever a login is attempted:

- if the last failed login time is *less* than "wariness timespan" in the past and the failed counter is equal to or greater than the threshold, do not process the login normally but instead present an error

Whenever a login fails:

- if the last failed login time is *more* than "wariness timespan" in the past, update the last failed login time to now and reset the count of failed logins to zero
- unconditionally increase the count of failed logins by one

Whenever a login succeeds:

- reset both the last failed login time and the failed login count

Regarding the original question: clearing cookies will not destroy the user session information (that should be stored on the server) but it will effectively leave it orphaned, and it will stay around until the session GC mechanism kicks in and cleans it up.

Comment: Attempts by one person (trying to guess coworker accounts) is just as bad as someone trying to get into a single account. Do you have any examples of "session spanning?" What about false positives from a corporate network?

Comment: @AbsoluteƵERØ: I wrote "destroy *the user session information*" (data), not "the session". Re your second comment: first, that's not how I interpret the question; second, protecting accounts with a timeout will make attacks effectively worthless -- making many worthless attacks in parallel is as harmless as making just one, so I 'm not sure how one person trying to guess coworker accounts changes the picture; third, if one wants to log the IP address for each failed attempt (to identify the source) I 'm not stopping them. I don't understand what you are trying to say about false positives.

Comment: I'm not sure where that first comment came from. (I'm sure it was meant for someone else.) All data from every attack is helpful if you're trying to figure out how someone exploited your site. No attack is ever harmless. It takes bandwidth and resources (including your time) trying to figure out what happened. Attempts aren't necessarily attacks. In your scenario if someone tries to guess a co-worker's password. They guess twice, then the coworker returns they have 3 more tries since the slate's been wiped clean. They would be from the same IP (two different people).

Answer (score 0):

No, the user can't destroy the session. What the user can do is stop using it (by deleting cookies, for example).

Sessions work this way:

1. The server creates a session and generates a unique id.
2. The server sends the unique id to the client and it is stored locally by the browser as a cookie.
3. Every time the user (browser) wants to reload the session, simply sends the cookie info when loading a page.
4. Your server recognizes the unique id sent to it and reloads the session (basically, your PHP scripts, if you use PHP, will regenerate the session variables, that's all).

From now on, every request the client does to your website will include the unique id as cookie data. But what if the user deletes the cookie? The session won't be used, but it's still stored in your server (until the expire time occurs).

Comment: And, trying to solve your problem... the best way would be to store inside a database an identifier for the user (username, for example) and the number of times he tried to do the action you want. That way, when he tries to do that, you can compare the data passed with the database data and do the proper action.

Answer (score 0):

Sessions store data in 2 different places, if it's a cookie-based session.

There is a unique identifier issued to the client, and the information based on that unique ID is stored server-side, linked to that identifier.

When a user clears the cookies, only their session identifier is removed from the client side only, but not the actual data tied to the identifier. Normally speaking, a user logging back in or logging into the same account will just simply be issued a new session ID. Essentially, destroying cookies simply destroys the link to the data because the user no longer holds the session identifier.

However, it's possible to use an internal account ID as a session identifier, which can hold a global count of how many users are logged into 1 particular account. You'll want to looking at manually setting session ID using: http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php and setting the ID with your own internal account identifier.

One very simple solution is to have a $_SESSION variable be linked to user's account IDs using session_id(). On login, you could start the session with the user ID, and then increment up a session variable (something like $_SESSION['logged_in_count']++). On logout, start the user session with the ID set as the user ID, and decrement (like $_SESSION['logged_in_count']--). This way, you can set up logic in the login script to prevent any new log ins based on some maximum # of concurrent connections that a user may have. This is just one simple example, but you can also add in timestamps to the mix, or any other types of constraints to make the logic closer to what your ideal flow would be.

Comment: Sometimes sessions are also transferred across the address bar.